# Difference between %lli and %lld in printf and scanf?

Tags: c++, c, printf

My friend and I were arguing about `%lli` and `%lld`. I generally use `%lli`, and every time he argues to use `%lld` in `printf` and `scanf`. He claims `%lli` and `%lld` are different.

Is there any difference between the `%lli` and `%lld` format specifiers in GNU GCC compilers, or are they the same?

Comment: According to [this `printf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) they're not different.

Comment: http://www.nullstone.com/download/releasenotes-ns-c.htm Release 4.8
Implement C99 long long int format specifier: Use the C99 long long int format specifier "%lld" when printing long long int values.

Comment: Note that the properties of `printf()` and `scanf()` are more a question of what the library does than what the compiler does, though it is increasingly complex.

Answer (score 7):

For printf, they are exactly the same.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf

> `d`, `i` converts a signed integer into decimal representation [-]dddd.
>
> Precision specifies the minimum number of digits to appear. The default precision is 1.
>   If both the converted value and the precision are ​0​ the conversion results in no characters.

---

For scanf, they are different. Below is quote from documentation.

> `d` matches a decimal integer.
>   The format of the number is the same as expected by strtol() with the value 10 for the base argument
>
> `i` matches an integer.
>   The format of the number is the same as expected by strtol() with the value ​0​ for the base argument (base is determined by the first characters parsed)

In case of `i`, if your number starts with `0`, it will be parsed as octal.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf

Comment: so which one should be preferred in which case?

Comment: @HariomSingh if you can expect number in other base than 10, use `i`.

Comment: @HariomSingh You should use `d` by default unless you really need automatic base detection. With `i` numbers like `012` are read as octal, which is counter intuitive, considering how rare they are these days.

Comment: @HariomSingh: Note that dates are represented in base 10, so a date like 08/08/2017 or 09/09/2017 causes conniptions if you use `%i` and `scanf()` (because neither 8 nor 9 is an octal digit, so the 0 is one octal number, and the 8 or 9 is the next number).

Answer (score 3):

Possibly you should see documentation...?

For `printf()` they are equivalent, but they differ for `scanf()`.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

For specifier `d`, characters extracted from input stream are any number of decimal digits (0-9), optionally preceded by a sign (+ or -).

For `i` it's any number of digits, optionally preceded by a sign (+ or -).
Decimal digits assumed by default (0-9), but a **0 prefix introduces octal digits (0-7), and 0x hexadecimal digits (0-f)**.
Signed argument.